# convert hex number to std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I have a question on converting a hex number into a std_logic_vector. I need the bit representation of the hex numbers because they are my data the simulated keyboard is sending to my board (later). At now i am in development phase:
Here is the code example that doesn't work within ISE:

```
Subtype ScanCode is std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
variable binaryRep : ScanCode;
binaryRep := std_logic_vector(16#70F070#);
```

the conversion in the last line is where the problem appears the Compiler tells me Cannot convert type  universal_integer to type std_logic_vector

I have also tried that code but got another error i don't understand

```
binayRep <= to_stdlogicvector(x"FC");
```

this was the error message i got:

> Near to_stdlogicvector ; 2 visible identifiers match here

I also searched the web for other solutions but i couldn't solve the problem.
Has anyone an Idea how to fix the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`16#70F070#` is a numerical literal and isn't appropriate directly, it needs a conversion routine.  You don't have an appropriate conversion routine that matches the signature [integer return std_logic_vector].

This

```
binaryRep <= to_stdlogicvector(x"FC");
```

wouldn't work anyway because the equivalent bit string to `x"FC"` has a length of 8, while binaryRep has a length of 40 and you don't specify the length std_logic_vector to produce.  (And x"FC" already get's converted to an equivalent bit map).

The only to_stdlogicvector function declarations I found are in package fixed_generic_pkg and aren't appropriate.

you could:

```
binaryRep <= x"00000000FC";
```

Which matches the bit string length.

Or by including package numeric_std in a use clause:

```
binaryRep <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(16#70F070#,binaryRep'length));
```

Which converts a natural (an integer subtype) to an unsigned which is then type converted to std_logic_vector with the length derived from binaryRep.

Or using Mentor's std_logic_arith package

```
binaryRep <= to_std_logicvector(16#70F070#,binaryRep'length);
```

Which takes an integer argument and a natural length and converts the result to a std_logic_vector.

Or using Synopsys's std_logic_arith package

```
binaryRep <= conv_std_logic_vector(16#70F070#,binaryRep'length);
```

Where both arguments are type integer.

(And there are a couple more ways, dependent on VHDL-2008 support).

Answer (score 1):

**According to:**
https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/vhdl/v_hex.html

```
signal A : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"00000017";
```

**Worked** for me :)

Comment: With your recent edit, I don't see any added value with respect to the (3,5 yo) accepted answer.